# Office UI Fabric Component demo for specific version

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How can I get a demo of components for specific version of Office UI Fabric as I can see here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/button ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is through this link: https://fabricweb.azurewebsites.net/oufr/ but it gives you the inner dev loop demo site and not the official fabric website, which in most cases differs only by design and probably has some internal components that are not surfaced to the public.